# Вывод на печать кортежей из списка построчно

Tags: python, tuple

Как в принте распечатывать кортежи в списке один под другим, а не в строку? Не понимаю, как форматирование работает.

Вот мой код, если нитересно проверить.  Меня в нём всё устраивает, кроме конечного принта.  Как его отформатировать, чтобы он давал список кортежей один под другим?

```
goods = []

features = {'наименование': '', 'цена': '', 'количество': '', 'ед': ''}
analytics = {'наименование': [], 'цена': [], 'количество': [], 'ед': []}
number = 0

while True:
    if input('Выход - Q, \nЛюбая клавиша - продолжить: ').upper() == 'Q':
        break
    number += 1
    for f in features.keys():
        user_data = input(f'{f}: ')
        features[f] = int(user_data) if (f == 'цена' or f == 'количество') else user_data
        analytics[f].append(features[f])
    goods.append((number, features.copy()))
    print('Текущая аналитика по товарам:\n')
    for key, value in analytics.items():
        print(key, value)

print(goods)
```

Comment: очень сумбурно написано, вы бы вопрос перефразировали бы и было бы замечательно, если бы привели пример вывода (хоть в блокноте его напишите)

Comment: `print(*goods, sep='\n')`?